# -echoctl not being ackonowledged in forked program

Tags: bash, terminal, tty

Please,

I have a terminal application that requires no echoing of control characters back to the terminal.
I can happily issue 'stty -echoctl' at a terminal, run my application and obtain the result I am after. Further, I can include 'stty -echoctl' in .bashrc and everything is fine. (I have also added it to .profile but that seems to bring in .bashrc anyway)

I can then open another terminal (type 'konsole/gnome-terminal/xterm' in the original console and again I get the result I expect.

The problem I have (and this is in preparation of forking the program form another application) is that if i try

$ xterm -e ./V2.13

or even

$ xterm -e bash -c ./V2.13

the control characters are in fact echoed back to my app.??

EDIT:Additionally is there any need (benefit) in executing bash to execute my application ?

Comment: When you're running `stty -echoctl` you're changing the settings of the tty connected to your stdin. When you're running xterm, you're creating a **new tty**, which of course won't inherit the settings of the unrelated one it was started from

Comment: Notice that `-echoctl` will NOT prevent the terminal from echoing back control characters, but will only change the way in which they're echoed back. They will be echoed back as binary `\x02`, etc, instead of `^B`, etc.

Comment: So it basically comes down to why that application of yours needs control characters to be echoed back as binary garbage instead of in caret (`^C`, etc) notation. Maybe there's a better way out of it than messing with the terminal settings ;-)

Comment: @user414777 - but....I have stty -echoctl in .bashrc - I log on, open a terminal and things work fine. I create a new instance by running xterm from xterm and everything works fine - it is inheriting the settings

Comment: @user414777 - "echoing \x02" - not sure about this, all I know is that there are no control characters echoing on my application display.

Comment: **1.** that's because the interactive bash shell started in xterm is sourcing in the `.bashrc` file. When you run another program directly via `xterm -e ...`, it isn't. **2.** control characters may be "invisible" (eg. `printf 'a\x02b'` will appear as just `ab`), but they're still there. They're still echoed back -- run your program in `script(1)` to see it.

Comment: @user414777 - can you think why "$ xterm -e bash -c ./V2.13" is not working as expected then ?

Comment: "interactive" is the keyword. Only an *interactive* bash (or [one started by ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611107/414777)) will source `~/.bashrc` by default.

Comment: @user414777 -And that is the case with my application. I understood (and bear with me because I am only just starting to understand this) that if I run 'xterm -e ./V2.13' I am starting a terminal emulator (bash is not involved) and I can appreciate that tty has not been set but if I start a new instance of /xterm/bash' and pass it a command it should work just as thought I started 'xterm/bash' and then invoked my program (which does work as expected) It comes down to what is the difference between 'xterm -e 'bash -c ./V2.13' and 'xterm' and then running V2.13

Comment: Only the latter will start an interactive shell. If you want it to run a script and still be interactive, run it with `-i`: `xterm -e bash -ic ./V2.13`. But an interactive shell may have other differences than just sourcing `~/.bashrc`. You can search for `interactive` in `man bash` for all the (documented) differences and how bash determines if it's run "interactively" or not.

Comment: Thx @user414777 - I'll keep reading. So far I am bit confused as I am not running a script. I am running an executable.

Comment: and this @user414777 - does the trick..xterm -e bash -ci ./V2.13. The 'i' option tells bash to run interactively. Many thanks for your assistance

Comment: The argument of  `-c` is still a "script", just like a file containing just the `./V2.13` command, and you can put more than one command in it, e.g. `xterm -e bash -c 'stty -echoctl; ./V2.13'`

Comment: @user414777 - xterm -e bash -c 'stty -echoctl; ./V2.13' - I see. What about if I wanted to just run 'xterm -e ./V2.13' without bash. Am I able to set -echoctl in anyway ?

Comment: No, `xterm` only lets you change some terminal defaults via its `-tm`/`ttyModes` option. Not `echoctl`.

Comment: @user414777 - Infact you can !! (should of tried it first before I posted).  xterm -e 'stty -echoctl; ./V2.13' works happily.

Comment: That's because bash invokes a shell (i.e. bash) when the argument to `-e` is not an executable. `xterm -e 'a; b'` is the same as `xterm -e sh -c 'a; b'`.

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484566/414777), especially the example at the end for how xterm handles the argument(s) to `-e`.

Comment: Many thanks @user414777 you've been a great help. Cheers